# Repeat a string N times

Tags: bash, shell

In Python strings can be "multiplied" to repeat them a number of times:

```py
test="----"
print(test)

test="----"*10
print(test)

#output
----
----------------------------------------
```

Is there an equivalent in bash? I tried `*` but it doesn't work:

```sh
$ Test2="----"
$ echo $Test2
----
$ echo ${Test2}*5
----*5
$ echo $Test2*5
----*5
$ echo echo $[Test2]*5
-bash: ----: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "-")
$ echo $(Test2)*5
Test2: command not found
```

Comment: `printf -- "${Test2}%.s" {1..5}`

Comment: That is dangerous if `$Test2` might contain `%`, \, or other metacharacters `printf` will interpret.

Answer (score 3):

There's no equivalent shorthand, no. You can do it with an explicit loop like so:

```
test=""
for ((i=0; i<5; i++)); do test+="----"; done
```